# Crop raster to area with data pixel perfectly

Tags: qgis, raster, nodata

I have a raster file with some data pixels around the middle and a huge amount of NODATA padding everywhere around it.

How can I crop the raster so that the extent aligns with the outermost non-NODATA pixels on all sides?

The result should be perfectly aligned to the source raster's rows and columns (so, if possible, without a vector mask layer or an extent defined in CRS units).

Comment: What is the issue with a vector mask? I did a basic test with a raster with data pixels surrounded by NoData pixels, and a projected CRS. I used Raster Pixels to Polygons to create a polygon mask, and then Clip Raster By Extent with the polygon layer as a vector mask. The output layer was aligned to the source raster.

Comment: It might seem esoteric but I would be afraid of it being lossy in some circumstances due to floating point numbers etc. I want to do analysis on pixel-perfect aligned rasters, not 99.99% aligned ones.

Comment: Dear two people who votes to close this, please be nice and comment on what you feel the answer is lacking.

Comment: Have you seen raster grids go out of alignment before? Just trying to understand if this is a real issue or a theoretical one. Keep in mind that you can run checks on the before/after rasters to ensure that the differences are zero.

Comment: Theoretical, to be honest. Thank you!

Comment: Dear one person under the pseudonym @bugmenot123 1) In the published question, it is desirable to show pictures before and after what you want to get. 2) What geo-tools did you use to get the desired result and what didn't satisfy you.
3) As it is, it is more theoretical than practical. P.S. Maybe auto-translation also introduces unclear points...:-)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gdal_translate https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html with `-srcwin` option.

> **-srcwin <xoff> <yoff> <xsize> <ysize>**
>
> Selects a subwindow from the source image for copying based on
> pixel/line location.

Offsets are counted from the top left corner. A separate challenge is to analyze the data/nodata coverage for finding the appropriate values for offsets and sizes.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the right approach.